# Evaluating the value of $\int_0^1 e^{\left(x^2\right)}~dx+\int_1^e\sqrt{\ln x}~dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluate the value of: $$\int_0^1 e^{\left(x^2\right)}~dx+\int_1^e\sqrt{\ln x}~dx$$

---

**Here is what I have tried:**

$\ln x >\sqrt{\ln x}$ when $x=[1,e]$

$e^x>e^{\left(x^2\right)}$ when $x=[0,1]$

And after that put under the integral and obtain:

$$\int_0^1 e^{\left(x^2\right)}~dx+\int_1^e\sqrt{\ln x}~dx\leq e$$

And it is easy to see:

$$e\geq \int_0^1 e^{\left(x^2\right)}~dx + \int_1^e\sqrt{\ln x}~dx>1$$

But it is not solved just I know is smaller than $e$ and bigger than $1$

I can write a series but it will only give me an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can obtain a relationship between the two integrals via the substitution $x=e^{u^2}$ and integration by parts: $$\begin{align}\int_1^e \sqrt{\ln{x}}~dx&=\int_0^1 u\cdot 2ue^{u^2}~du\\&=\left[e^{u^2}u\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 e^{u^2}~du\\&=e-\int_0^1 e^{u^2}~du \tag{1}\end{align}$$
Hence, we deduce from $(1)$ that:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^1 e^{x^2}~dx+\int_1^e \sqrt{\ln{x}}~dx=e}$$

Comment: please explain me  first row step by step

Comment: @IcaSandu: it is already explained: perform the substitution $x\mapsto e^{u^2}$, then apply integration by parts.

Comment: in left you have integral from 1 to e and in right you have  integral from 0 to 1  i dont understand how you change limit's of integral

Comment: i understand thank you ;)

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**: If $f$ is an increasing function on the interval $[a,b]$ and $f^{-1}$ is its inverse function, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions)

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = b\,f(b)-a\, f(a). \tag{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_0^1 e^{x^2}\ dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(1)$

and

$\int\limits_1^e \sqrt{\ln (x)}\ dx = e-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(1)$ (as projectilemotion showed)...

so the sum equals $e$.